# Map marker symbol in TikZ (symbol with em and ex units doesn’t scale properly)

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Since there is no map marker symbol in the symbols list (at least I could not find it) I decided to draw it with TikZ. This is it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \newcommand{\point}{\tikz{
       \draw [rounded corners,blue, fill=blue](0,0) .. controls (-.05em,.2ex) and (-.3em,1.2ex) .. (0em,2.2ex) .. controls (.3em,1.2ex) and (.05em,.2ex) .. (0,0);
       \draw [blue,fill=white](0,1.15ex) circle (0.12em);}
}
\begin{document}
\tiny tiny \point text

\normalsize normal \point text

\Huge huge \point text
\end{document}
```

The problem is that it does not scale properly if I change the font size, for example `{\Large text \point text}`

[image: problem with scaling]

Do I need to draw a different symbol for each size I use or is there a way to let it scale properly?

Comment: It scales, but the problem is that `em` and `ex` don’t scale the same way. You should use either one of the units …

Comment: @Tobi So it's not ex for height and em for width?

Comment: @Tobi, I mean as a general rule

Comment: In general it is – or was. Nowdays the `em` is often defined as the _height_ of the font (10pt here). It makes sense to use `em` for width and `ex` for height but nobody cares if you don’t use them that was. Unfortunately it doesn't scale correct when you use only on of the units. I’m searching for a solution …

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: as a side note, the `fontawesome` package does have a Map Marker, called `\faicon{map-marker}`. But only works with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the `rounded corners` part, which is not relative to the font size. So the solution is to set `rounded corners=<x>ex`, then it depends on the font size. The following example shows a solution an illustrated the problem with simple corners: `\cornerI` is rounded with the absolute same radius, while `\cornerII` is rounded with a radius proportional to the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\point}{\tikz{
    \filldraw [rounded corners=0.6ex,blue] (0,0)
        .. controls (-.05em,.2ex) and (-.3em,1.2ex)
        .. (0em,2.2ex) .. controls (.3em,1.2ex) and (.05em,.2ex) .. (0,0);
    \draw [blue,fill=white](0,1.15ex) circle (0.12em);
}}

\newcommand{\cornerI}{\tikz{
    \draw [rounded corners] (0,0) -| (2ex,2ex);
}}
\newcommand{\cornerII}{\tikz{
    \draw [rounded corners=0.6ex] (0,0) -| (-2ex,2ex);
}}

\begin{document}
\tiny text \point\ text \cornerI\,\cornerII

\normalsize text \point\ text \cornerI\,\cornerII

\Huge text \point\ text \cornerI\,\cornerII
\end{document}
```

[image: rounded corners]

---

Furthermore it’s not a good idea to mix `em` and `ex` because they don’t scale the same way. Hav a look at the following example: The `\Square` is perfect for `\Huge` but not for smaller sizes.

[image: squares]

The reason is that the ratio 1em/1ex isn’t the same for all font sizes …

[image: font size]

… and it even depends on the font itself.

[image: font family]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,parskip}


\makeatletter
\newlength{\tmpa}
\newlength{\tmpb}
\newlength{\tmpc}
\newcommand{\EmExTest}[2][Computer Modern]{{%
   #2%
   \setlength{\tmpa}{1em}%
   \setlength{\tmpb}{1ex}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpc{\tmpb/\tmpa}%
   \normalsize#1 at \textbackslash\expandafter\@gobble\string#2:
   \[
      \frac{1\,\mathrm{ex}}{1\,\mathrm{em}}
      = \frac{\strip@pt\tmpb\,\mathrm{pt}}{\strip@pt\tmpa\,\mathrm{pt}}
      = \tmpc
   \]\par
}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Square}{\tikz{
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (10em,21.31ex);
}}

\begin{document}
\EmExTest{\tiny}
\EmExTest{\normalsize}
\EmExTest{\Huge}

\tiny \Square\quad
\normalsize \Square\quad
\Huge \Square

\EmExTest{\normalsize}% Computer Modern
\EmExTest[Palatino]{\normalsize\fontfamily{pxr}\selectfont}
\EmExTest[Helvetica]{\normalsize\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd move the inner circle a bit more north, but it works properly now.

Comment: Move the circle whereever you like ;-) See my edit the wrong scaling is a result of absolute `rounded corners` value _and_ mixing `em` and `ex` …

Comment: And just another note: You can use `\filldraw` instead of `\draw [fill]`; and `\draw [blue,fill=blue]` is the same as `\draw [blue,fill]` …

Comment: "1em/1ex isn’t the same for all sizes" and it depends on the type.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Thanks! I added an example with different font families …