# Code for pin icon on a map

Tags: graphics, symbols

Is there any way I can get the pin icon / symbol (that us usually used on maps)? Any icon similar to the attached one would do. I am trying to use this symbol instead of stating 'Address' in one of my documents. Any input, suggestions or advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147017/map-marker-symbol-in-tikz-symbol-with-em-and-ex-units-doesn-t-scale-properly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Actually, this does not mean address but location. For an address, I would take a house symbol.

Comment: @Harry +1 for your promise below to contribute here in time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `tikz` solution (as standalone image):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\pinA
\newdimen\pinB
\newdimen\pinC

\setlength{\pinA}{10mm}
\setlength{\pinB}{20mm}
\setlength{\pinC}{40mm}

\definecolor{pin}{gray}{0}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-\pinB, -\pinC) (\pinB, \pinB);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pinAngle}{acos(\pinB/\pinC)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pinAngleRight}{270+\pinAngle}%
    \path[fill=pin, even odd rule]
      (\pinAngleRight:\pinB)
      arc[
        at={(0,0)},
        start angle=\pinAngleRight,
        delta angle=360-2*\pinAngle,
        radius=\pinB,
      ]
      -- (0, -\pinC) -- cycle
      circle[
        at={(0,0)},
        radius=\pinA,
      ]
    ;  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The both radii and the length of the tip can be configured using the dimen registers `\pinA`, `\pinB`, `\pinC`, all three measured from the origin in the middle of the circles. The color can be set via color name `pin`.

### Usage

The file can be stored as `pin.tex`, then run `pdflatex pin` to get `pin.pdf`.
The following example automatically scales the image to the size of uppercase letters, when included as image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\pin}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\heightof{M}]{pin}%
}

\begin{document}
{\Huge \pin~Hello World}
{\normalsize \pin~Hello World}
{\tiny \pin~Hello World}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result usage]

Comment: Wow! This is very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there anyway, I can shrink the size of this symbol? Its huge on the document. I am sorry, but I am very new to Latex.

Comment: @Harry It can be scaled, when included, e.g, `\includegraphics[scale=.25]{pin.pdf}` or `\includegraphics[height=\heightof{M}]{pin.pdf}` (the latter requires `\usepackage{calc}`. Or you can change the length settings of `\pinA`, `\pinB`, `\pinC`.

Comment: Hello. Changing the length settings helped. Thanks a bunch. Cheers - Harry

Comment: Everybody here in the TeX community is very helpful and friendly. Keep up the good work guys!!! I hope to be able to help other newbies with their questions in the near future. :-)

Answer (score 22):

You can use the command `\faMapMarker` from the package `fontawesome`. Like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
Map Symbol: \faMapMarker
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: simple map marker from fontawesome]

This symbol is available in `pdflatex` now as well, since the `fontawesome`-package added support for `pdflatex` recently.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. I am using pdfLaTeX. I am not sure if the fontawesome package would work with pdfLaTeX. I will give it a shot in any case and report back.

Comment: @Harry no, it won't. Just in case, you haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Harry it's possible you might have nothing to lose by using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for this particular document. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex).

Comment: Icons reference: https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf